# General Link - Raw Value inside but not editable in Field

Tags: content-editor, links

I have a general link field where the value is still inside when I look at the raw value but the field seems to be empty and has to be cleared before it is editable again. How do I fix that and what is causing this issue?

I am using Sitecore 8.1 rev 151207 and the value of the link is:

```
<link text="Link to Service" linktype="internal" class="" title="" target="" querystring="" id="{FBCDB96C-7896-401B-A77F-0B5201FBCD91}" anchor="" />
```

Note that this is not a broken link. In the Content Editor, the value is fine but in the Experience Editor when you open the fields for editing the link is empty. If I go back to the content editor and look at the raw values for the field I can see the above.

Comment: Can you at least share the raw value?

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: This normally happens when you are referring to an item that doesn't exist anymore or might not be linked properly. If you see the quick link section you should see a broken link for this.

Comment: ^ the above comment should be marked as answer :) I think

Comment: The Sitecore Version is Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151207
It is not a broken link. In the Content Editor the Value is ok but in the Experience Editor if you open the fields for edit in the Field Editor the general link will be empty although there is a value inside
eg:<link text="Link to Service" linktype="internal" class="" title="" target="" querystring="" id="{FBCDB96C-7896-401B-A77F-0B5201FBCD91}" anchor="" /> The link on the page is also working fine - you just can't see it for editing.

Comment: Can you just provide the code which renders the link field in Experience Editor?

Comment: @Kodachi do you have a custom link provider by any chance?

Comment: Can you try clicking the clear button above the link field in content editor and update the link field again and check if issue still persisting?

Comment: @AlokBhatt - Clearing the Link field and repopulation is working. But the link might disappear again in the field (while still working fine because it is saved but not shown)